# Laravel 5 route pagination url encoding issue

Tags: php, laravel, encoding, pagination, laravel-5

I built a laravel 5 application and now I am testing how it handles different inputs. Thus I encountered a weird problem. In the header I have a search field. It returns results, paginated by 10.

**The problem**

If a user inputs a letter, for an example "e" in English, everything works just fine. However, when a user enters a letter, for an example "e" in Bulgarian - the first page of the results is shown correctly and when a user hits page 2 the query in the search from "е" in Bulgarian changes to "%D0%B5" and no more results are shown. Here is an actual link to the website. http://podobri.eu

I guess this has something to do with the encoding but I can't see what I am doing wrong.

**Here is the actual code**

Route

```
Route::get('/search', [
   'uses' => '\Podobri\Http\Controllers\SearchController@getResults',
    'as'=>'search.results',
]);
```

SearchController

```
public function getResults(Request $request){

        $query = $request->input('query');
        $comments = Comment::where(function($query){
           return $query; 
        })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        if(!$query || $query==''){
            return view('problems.index')->with('comments', $comments);
        }

        $problems = Problem::where(DB::raw("CONCAT(problem_title, ' ', problem_description)"), 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                ->orWhere('location', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                ->orWhere('category', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

        Carbon::setLocale('bg');
        return view('search.results')
                ->with('comments', $comments)
                ->with('problems', $problems)
                ->with('title', 'Резултати за "'."$query".'" | Подобри')
                ->with('description', 'Резултати за "'."$query".'" в системата на Подобри');
    }
```

View

```
        @foreach($problems as $problem)
           <div>
              @include('problems.partials.problemblock')
           </div>
        @endforeach

        <!-- Paginating-->
        {!! $problems->appends(Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
```

Search form

```
<form action="{{ route('search.results') }}" role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-left head-form-responsive">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" required id='searchQuery' title="Търсете за проблеми" value="{{ Request::input('query') }}" name="query" class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Търсете за проблеми"/>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" id='searchBtn' class="btn btn-default">Търсете</button>
                </form>
```

Comment: when you hit page2 this action method is the same that is processing data?

Comment: I am not clear on what you mean. Have I done something considered bad practice?

Comment: No I mean this method getResults() is the same one use to go to page2 ?

Comment: Have you tried changing `$query = $request->input('query');` to `$query = urldecode($request->input('query'));`?

Comment: I can answer for him, and yes @яша, it's the same. Laravel paginate it adding `&page=X` at the end of the url

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I marked an answer as correct already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like your issue is happening because the paginator is appending a trailing slash with some odd redirect (not sure if you guys are using custom htaccess). Example, if you search for e, this is the URL:

```
http://podobri.eu/search?query=e
```

However, the URL for the second page is this:

```
http://podobri.eu/search/?query=e&page=2
```

Notice the slash in front of `?query`. If you remove the slash, it works. So, how can you fix this?

This was actually fixed a few months ago. You can see this commit here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/806fb79f6e06f794349aab5296904bc2ebe53963

So, if you are using L5.1 or 5.2, you can run `composer update`, and it'll fix itself. However, if you are using 5.0, it seems like it still has this bug so you can use the `setPath` method and try this instead:

```
{!! $problems->setPath('')->appends(Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
```

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.0. Tried your solution. Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and my solution was changed the method of the route.

```
Route::post('uri', 'Controller@function')
    ->name ('view.function');
```

for:

```
Route::any('uri', 'Controller@function')
    ->name ('view.function');
```

It's works for me.

Regards and good luck.