# Search query lost on pagination in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination

I'm quite new to laravel and backend stuff altogether so this might be a newb question!

My website has a search engine which is used to look up users.

Right now I'm using a pretty simple search controller, below is the code.

```
class SearchController extends Controller {
public function getResults(Request $request) {
    $query = $request->input('query');

    if (!$query) {
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    $users = User::where(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)"), 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->where('role', '=', 2)
    ->orWhere('username', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->where('role', '=', 2)
    ->orWhere('profile_text', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->where('role', '=', 2)
    ->orWhere('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->where('role', '=', 2)
    ->simplePaginate(1);




    return view('search.results')->with('users', $users);
 }
}
```

And the results page:

```
@extends('templates.default')

 @section('content')
    <h3>Results for "{{ Request::input('query') }}"</h3>


    @if (!$users->count())
        <p>No results found, sorry.</p>
    @else

    <div class="resultRow">
        <div class="">
            @foreach ($users as $user)
                     {{ $user->username }}
            @endforeach

        {!! $users->render() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
@stop
```

So if I were to search "John", I'd get the result of all the Johns, with the URL being http://localhost/search?query=John .

However, if I were to click on the next page of results (http://localhost/search?page=2), the query is lost, so my search controller just sends me back to my home page.

How do I keep the query through pagination?

EDIT: I'm pretty sure my problem is that it's going through the search controller once again after it click on page 2, but I have no idea how I would fix that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switched

```
{!! $users->render() !!}
```

with

```
{!! $users->appends(Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
```

Works like a charm. Credit goes to : [Laravel 5 route pagination url encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212580/laravel-5-route-pagination-url-encoding-issue?rq=1) (unrelated issue)

Comment: For me needed bit editing, but it really works like charm {{ $companies->appends(Request::all())->links() }} Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

in your `getResult` function, pass a `$query` variable to the view

```
return view('search.results', ['users' => $users, 'query' => $query]);
```

Then in your view, appends the query or other variables you need

```
{{ $users->appends(['query' => $query])->links() }}
```

you can check more in [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#displaying-results-in-a-view)

Answer (score 1):

You can use paginate the following way.

```
$users->withQueryString()->links()
```