# Call to undefined method appends()

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I created a filter for db table, but filtration just work for first page

I try this code in controller

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user=User::orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
    if($request->get('search'))
    {
        if ($request->get('type')) {
            $user->where('type', $request->get('type'));
        }
        if ($request->get('id')) {
            $user->where('id', (integer)$request->get('id'));
        }
        if ($request->get('first_name')) {
            $user->where('first_name', $request->get('first_name'));
        }
        if ($request->get('email')) {
            $user->where('email', $request->get('email'));
        }
    }


    $users = $user->paginate(20);
    $user->appends(['search' => $request->get('search')]);
    return view('admin.user.index', compact('users'));
}
```

But I get this error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::appends()
```

How I can fix this error or how I can make filter works with all pages ?

Comment: $user->appends(['search' => $request->get('search')]);

Comment: I don't think there is any `appends()` function in laravel

Comment: Is there a `appends` method ?

Comment: What are you trying here `$user->appends(['search' => $request->get('search')]);` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39326206/pagination-for-search-results-laravel-5-3 I see this example and try it

Comment: how I can make filter works with all pages ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Comment: Ok, thanks for the updating me

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you have used following line and paginate the user data in users

```
$users = $user->paginate(20);
```

So you need to use users variable instead of user

```
$users->appends(['search' => $request->get('search')]);
```